# what is modifiable Rvalue?

Tags: c++, c++11

Would someones please give an example of "modifiable rvalue"? My understanding is rvalue appeared on the right side of "=" in an expression. 
I tested the following example but I am not sure whether it explains the "modifiable rvalue"

```
int i=1
int &j = i;
j=2;  //cout: i == 2,
```

Answer (score 6):

It somewhat depends on the context for the phrase "modifiable rvalue." However, this is one possible example:

```
struct Modifiable
{
  int x;
  void modify() { std::cout << x << '\n'; x = -x; std::cout << x << '\n'; }
};

Modifiable demo()
{
  Modifiable m;
  m.x = 42;
  return m;
}

int main()
{
  demo().modify();
}
```

The return value of `demo()` is an rvalue (even a prvalue, in fact), but is modified by the call to `modify()`.

[[Live example]](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b204ad4fe7260fdb)